# Long Division - confused over different answers

Tags: divisibility

I'm re-learning manual long division because I'm trying to code it, but I am confused and befuddled because the manual process gives me a different answer from that which I get using the divide function in LibreOffice Calc.

### Calc answer:

92068282 / 36 = 2557452.27777778 (rounded)

### Manual steps:

`2557452.22222
  +--------------
36|92068282.00000
  -72v|||||||||||
   200|||||||||||
  -180v||||||||||
    206||||||||||
   -180v|||||||||
     268|||||||||
    -252v||||||||
      162||||||||
     -144v|||||||
       188|||||||
      -180v||||||
         80||||||
        -72v|||||
          80|||||
         -72v||||
           80||||
          -72v|||
            80|||
           -72v||
             80||
            -72v|
              80|
             -72|
              ...`
What have I missed?
Have I found the plug hole in the mathematical universe?
Are we all about to get sucked into a swirling galactic vortex?
D8 !

Answer (score 2):

You missed bringing down the last $2$ in the dividend.  That would add $\frac 2{36}\approx $0.055556$ to your answer.

Comment: Oops! Well spotted, and THANK YOU! So I did :P Galactic Vortex averted :D